# IBM ILOG ODM 8.5 - How to keep Decision Center Rules Code and Rule Designer Source Code Repository Synchronized

Tags: ilog

I would like to make sure that the execution of a script, can compare two files and keep the both the repositories synchronized i.e. Source Code Repository and Decision Center Repository.

Scenario 1
The two files would be 
1) Rule that is checked in from Rule Designer into Source Code Repository.

In this case, the rule is modified in Rule Designer but not Published to IBM Decision Center. so the script shall push the latest rule checked into source code repository ( SVN / GIT / VCS / PVCS ) to IBM Decision Center

2) Rule that is modified using the Enterprise / Business Console of Decision Center needs to be compared on execution of the script into the Source Code Repository ( SVN / GIT / VCS / PVCS )

Can we work with the decision center API to fetch a rule and compare?

Please leave a comment if my question was not clear so that I can clarify.

API to fetch the rules IlrSessionFactory and then compare

Comment: Quite an interesting question. I shall give a try. Thanx ACK.

Comment: Thanks Akif. please let me know, if you have any questions